# Azure Cosmos Java SDK overriding default retry values?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Cosmos SDK Version 4.10.0. I would like to know is there a way to override the retry values for Exception other than throttling Exception. I know that throttled requests (429) can be override using ThrottlingRetryOptions.

Some other exceptions which have retries are

1. Network Failures: Max retries - 120
2. GoneExceptions
3. PartitionIsMigratingException

Default values:

```
Backoff Constants 

private final static int DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 30;
//Note: Wait time in seconds after which the exception is logged with following warning: ""Received {} after backoff/retry. Will fail the request.{exception}". No further retries are attempted after this duration.
private final static int MAXIMUM_BACKOFF_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 15;
//Note: Maximum time in seconds a backoff occurs
private final static int INITIAL_BACKOFF_TIME = 1; // in seconds
private final static int BACK_OFF_MULTIPLIER = 2;
```

We don't want our client to wait for 30 seconds due to a network issue and return a failure say after 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you want to get a function to change default timeout? If so, can [this document](https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-java/1.0.0/index.html?com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/ConnectionPolicy.html) help you?

Comment: I am referring to the following version  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-cosmos/4.10.0 
Document here [this](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-cosmos/latest/index.html)

There is only a Retry Class for throttle request.

Comment: [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/master/direct-impl/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/internal/directconnectivity/GoneAndRetryWithRetryPolicy.java)?

Comment: @Tiny-wa [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/implementation/directconnectivity/GoneAndRetryWithRetryPolicy.java)
Same file ..But I think this is the latest SDK version.
Following values are present in this file
`private final static int DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 30;
        private final static int MAXIMUM_BACKOFF_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 15;
        private final static int INITIAL_BACKOFF_TIME = 1;
        private final static int BACK_OFF_MULTIPLIER = 2;`
Can we override these ?

Comment: Override it ,and starting the program locally and unplug the network cable or disconnecting the wireless network, that's what I can think about to test it.

Comment: Have you solved your problem or any progress? I mean that when you solved your problem, you can post your answer here so that it may help others if you don't mind it.

Answer (score 0):

Java SDK about request timeout and retry options:

[image]
[image]